# How can I solve the issue of getting an HTTPSConnectionPool "Max retries exceeeded with url" python requests error?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

As the title states, I continue to get this error and I have tried using a request Session object to then mount an adapter with a max retries option. Apparently it is still exceeding the retries, and I thought adding the adapter with a backoff factor would help the issue. Here is a code snippet of how I am doing this:

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong in adding this session adapter or is there a fix that works better for this problem?

This is what I am trying currently:

```
 session = requests.Session()
      retry = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504])
      adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
      session.mount('https://', adapter)
      resp = session.get("https://url.com",
              headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"})
```

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong in adding this session adapter or is there a fix that works better for this problem?

Comment: The usual cause of so many retries is simply that the url is wrong, or there is no webserver listening at that address.  Are you sure the url is correct?  Can you visit the same url in a regular browser?

Comment: Yes, absolutely certain it is the correct url.